# Thing to check if you have permissions to directory

Tags: python

I'm writting an python program and now I'm working at exceptions.

```
while True:
    try:
        os.makedirs("{}\\test".format(dest))
    except PermissionError:
        print("Make sure that you have access to specified path")
        print("Try again specify your path: ", end='')
        dest = input()
        continue
    break
```

It is working but later I need to delete that folder.
What is the better way to do it?

Comment: did you try `os.rmdir(path)` ?

Comment: But I dont want to change anything in this directory, only check if I have permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't.

It is almost never worth verifying that you have permissions to perform an operation that your program requires. For one thing, permissions are not the only possible reason for failure. A delete may also fail because of a file lock by another program, for instance. Unless you have a *very* good reason to do otherwise, it is both more efficient and more reliable to just write your code to *try* the operation and then abort on failure:

```
import shutil

try:
    shutil.rmtree(path_to_remove) # Recursively deletes directory and files inside it
except Exception as ex:
    print('Failed to delete directory, manual clean up may be required: {}'.format(path_to_remove))
    sys.exit(1)
```

---

## Other concerns about your code

- Use `os.path.join` to concatenate file paths: `os.makedirs(os.path.join(dest, test))`. This will use the appropriate directory separator for the operating system.
- Why are you looping on failure? In real world programs, simply aborting the entire operation is simpler and usually makes for a better user experience.
- Are you sure you aren't looking for the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) library? It allows you to spit out a unique directory to the operating system's standard temporary location:

  ```
  import tempfile

  with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
      some_function_that_creates_several_files(tmpdir)
      for f in os.walk(tmpdir):
           # do something with each file
  # tmpdir automatically deleted when context manager exits

  # Or if you really only need the file
  with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
      tmpfile.write('my data')
      some_function_that_needs_a_file(tmpfile)
  # tmpfile automatically deleted when context manager exits
  ```

Comment: 100% agree. In Python speak, it's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission (EAFP), instead of Looking Before You Leap (LBYL). As a practical matter, things very often change between when you check for permission and when you actually try to use it. On a busy system, there are too many potential race conditions for LBYL to be a safe pattern.

Comment: @KirkStrauser And on a system that isn't busy, you're unlikely to have the problem anyway, since the script creates the directory to be deleted.

Comment: @maxmarsz Users *expect* to need to run the program again if something goes wrong. Looping infinitely has the major downside that it is no longer safe to call your script from another one when trying to automate something.

Comment: @maxmarsz I think it's better to inform the user about the error, abort the operation (exit the program with an error code if this is a terminal script, return to some other part of the interface if it's a GUI), and let the user decide what to do next. The user might decide to change the input and try again, or they might decide to give up for now and try again later. It is up to them. That is how real world programs normally behave.

Comment: @maxmarsz As I said, you don't. You just try to create the file or folder. If your program doesn't actually *do* anything with the location, then it doesn't actually need permissions and shouldn't check for them.

Comment: @maxmarsz That is a separate question. Most likely, there is already an explanation elsewhere. Search for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `os.access`.

> os.access(path, mode, *, dir_fd=None, effective_ids=False, follow_symlinks=True)
>
> Use the real uid/gid to test for access to path. Note that most operations will use the effective uid/gid, therefore this routine can be used in a suid/sgid environment to test if the invoking user has the specified access to path. mode should be F_OK to test the existence of path, or it can be the inclusive OR of one or more of R_OK, W_OK, and X_OK to test permissions. Return True if access is allowed, False if not.

For example:

```py
os.access("/path", os.R_OK)
```

And the mode contains:

```py
os.F_OK   # existence
os.R_OK   # readability
os.W_OK   # writability
os.X_OK   # executability
```

Refer: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.access

Comment: Look at the doc, it says that you shouldn't do your example for security purpose. But another (which is following right after in the doc).*

Comment: @IMCoins Thanks for pointing out my mistake, and I have modified the example.

Comment: @maxmarsz Sorry that I couldn't fully understand what you want.